# html input with background image

Tags: html, css

Hello guys i have set background image on my input text and text area but i have few little problems

I have attached image.
How i can change text start up position in Name text input?

and my text area is bigger then my background image

this is my Name text input with style

```
input type="text" name="txtName" class="input" />

.input
{
    border: 0px solid #444444;
    height:39px;
    width:346px;
    background:url(images/Contact_05.jpg) no-repeat right top; 
    color:#fff; 
    padding-left:4px; 
    font-size:20px;
    }
```

and here is my text area

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="0" class="inputMessage"></textarea>
.inputMessage
{
    border:0px solid #444444;  
    height:386px; 
    width:685px;
    background:url(images/Contact_20.jpg) no-repeat left top; 
    padding-left:4px; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-size:20px; resize:none;
    }
```

any advice? [image]

Comment: Can you clarify at all? For the input boxes you might want to add a few pixels of padding-left. For the text-area maybe a bit of padding-right.

Comment: If you're able to use CSS3, then you can do the whole thing with no images. `textarea {border-radius:5px;}` will give you a good start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the padding-left to a greater value on your inputs, and decrease the width of your textarea.

When you're designing your form it would be good to put a temporary border around your inputs to see where they are actually positioned, and when you're done just take it off.

Answer (score 1):

```
padding:10px;
```

(or more) on `input` and `textarea`.