# How can i give Input style title background?

Tags: css, forms, input, background, title

I wanted input title background, but it is not working after refresh:

```
<form name="spe_form" method="post" action="">
  <label for="tag-title" >Widget title</label>
  <input name="spe_title" style="color:#cf0000" type="text" id="spe_title" 
    value="<?php echo $spe_title; ?>" size="10" />
</form>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all if I am to believe that you are adding title background from the variable $spe_title then that is wrong.

Every time you refresh the page you would need to re initialise the same.

Also, if you want to add background to the input field you have not added any css to the field to add a background.

If you are looking for some text to be displayed in the input box like "Widget Title goes here" then you should look at input masking javascript/jquery libraries

Have you seen [html input with background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843571/html-input-with-background-image)?