# Overlap "input text" over a image

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to give a way that the user can give a tittle to a image and write over a image, so my viable solution is to have 2 textfield when the second one is update with the string we introduced in the first input.

Here is the code:

```
<form action="#" id="form_field">
    <input type="text" id="textfield1" value="" onChange="document.getElementById('textfield2').value=this.value">
    <input type="text" id="textfield2" value="">
</form>
```

Is there any form to insert that "input text" over a image? i will hide the box with css after that so its look like you can write something over a image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a input with position absolute.

Take a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/x60cgyeh/2/

```
<form action="#" id="form_field">
    <input type="text" id="textfield2" value="" placeholder="Insert image title...">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300/eee/aaa">
</form>
```

and CSS

```
#form_field {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
}

#textfield2 {
    position:absolute;
    background:transparent;
    border:0;
    color:#000;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    top:20px;
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What browsers do you need this to work in?  If it is just the modern ones you can set the size and background image of the input field itself.

See: [html input with background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843571/html-input-with-background-image)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a background-image to the `<form>` tag using CSS like this: **[jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sokzepyt/6/)**

HTML:

```
<form action="#" id="form_field">
    <input type="text" id="textfield1" value="" onChange="document.getElementById('textfield2').value=this.value" placeholder="Enter Image Title">
    <input type="text" id="textfield2"  placeholder="Enter Image Description" value="">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form#form_field {
    width: 600px;
    height: 359px;
    background-image: url(//bg image url)
}
form#form_field input {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    color: white;
}
form#form_field input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```