# Image background for a number field

Tags: html, css

I currently have a [Form: including Number field, image button, and image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I8kM.png) and I want to change the number field so that the background is a similar image. Here's my HTML

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="sendSMSTelstra.php" method = "post">
<input type="number" class="input" min ="0" max = "1440" onChange="checkFilled(1);" name="timeField1" id="timeField1" value="">
 <input type="image" name="imageField1" id="imageField1" onmouseup= "SendCMD(1)" onmousedown="changeImage(1)" src="img/ButtonBlueb.png" width="42" height="42" value="">

    <img src="img/on.png" alt="" width="40" height="40" id="IO1" name="IO1"/>
```

I've been fiddling around with CSS, but nothing seems to work. Here's one of my attempts.

```
                       .input
                            {
                                border: 0px solid #444444;
                                height:39px;
                                width:50px;
                                background:url(img/white.png) no-repeat right top; 
                                padding-left:4px; 
                                }
```

Any advice would be great!

Comment: Do you have any CSS?

Comment: Just use a background image in your CSS.

Comment: Share css code if any. @mike

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html input with background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843571/html-input-with-background-image)

Comment: I deleted my CSS a while ago - I'm trying to undo my code, but it's not letting me. I'll try to write what I attempted

Answer (score 1):

You can use specific color for background or image itself as a background.

```
#timeField1{
background-color : #d1d1d1;   
}
```

OR

```
 #timeField1{
 background-image : url('img/on.png');   
 background-size: 80px 15px; /*optional*/
 }
```

also check for font color in input for user experience.